# Create an associative array in jquery using php array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to create an assosiative array in jQuery from PHP.

Here is my script so far. `selectedStoresDict` is `json` encoded array with values `["Lahore", "Islamabad"]`

```
var selectedStores = <?php echo $selectedStoresDict; ?>;
var data = {};
for( i = 0 ; i <= selectedStores.length; i++) {
   data['id'] = i;
   data['text'] = selectedStores[i];
}

console.log(data, "Hello, world!");
```

However my console is showing that its not an array. I want something like this:

```
 [{ id: 1, text: 'Lahore' }, { id: 2, text: 'Islamabad' }]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this should be a JS question instead of a PHP one, but here you have. You were almost there:

```
var selectedStores = <?php echo $selectedStoresDict; ?>;
var data = [];
for( i = 1 ; i <= selectedStores.length; i++) {
   data.push({
      id: i,
      text: selectedStores[i]
   });
}

console.log(data, "Hello, world!");
```

An array in JS is represented with [], so you need to initialize it like that, then just push the info (in this case, and object with keys and values). Also for ids starting with 1, you must initialize i = 1.

Comment: you need `id: i + 1` to get the id values you're looking for

Comment: Oh, that's true. I edited my answer. With my old wnaser you would end with ids starting with 0 instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

No need to loop thru.

Just json_encode the array

```
<?php
$selectedStoresDict[] = array("id"=>1,"text"=>"Lahore");
$selectedStoresDict[] = array("id"=>2,"text"=>"Islamabad");
?>

<script>
console.log('<?php echo json_encode($selectedStoresDict); ?>');
</script>
```